# Installing ROracle on Mac OS X - what is needed from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, macos, r

I tried to install ROracle today, after having managed to install RPostgreSQL and RMySQL on my Mac OS X. Unfortunately, the Oracle website drives me crazy. I just cannot figure out which minimum package I need to install in order to use ROracle. Intuitively I thought I just need a client and downloaded the instant client.

Is this enough? Where should I put the unzipped instant client?
I also tried SQLDeveloper but my setup seems lack some Oracle installation seems still.
If I start compiling anyway:

```
R CMD INSTALL Roracle.tar.gz
```

I end up with the following error:

You must set the shell variable ORACLE_HOME to the
   directory where Oracle resides and re-run R CMD INSTALL
   e.g., (using Bourne shell syntax):

```
  export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle
  R CMD INSTALL ROracle
```

So my simple question is, which package do I need to install and which location do you recommend? Setting up the compiler is not the problem here (at least so far :) )

Note I just want to connect to some database which is NOT on my system, so I really should just need a client (if ROracle allows for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an Oracle client installation you should be able to use the Oracle Instant Client. For documentation and download see [Instant Client Downloads for Mac OS X (Intel x86)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) . Depending on what type of client you need you have a list of choices there.
The [Basic Client](http://download.oracle.com/otn/mac/instantclient/10204/instantclient-basic-10.2.0.4.0-macosx-x64.zip) is allways needed and you could add a supplemental package to it depending on your needs. The basic client will work for many.

Choose a location to for ORACLE_HOME (/Application/oracle/product/client/10.2)
create a lib directory in that ORACLE_HOME/
unzip the basic client and put the *dylib* files in ORACLE_HOME/lib.
ORACLE_HOME=/Application/oracle/product/client/10.2
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

If you need a more complete client, check wich supplemental installation you need and add it to the $ORACLE_HOME that you build here. If you need jdbc, add the jdbc supplement, if you need sqlplus, add the sqlplus supplement. Make sure that executables go to $ORACLE_HOME/bin/

Comment: quite some hustle for just a client installation, probably I just could not believe all these pre-installation task were necessary and thus though I was wrong... Thanks for your explanation and patience.

Comment: @ran2: yes, you are right, Oracle on the mac is not like we are used to..... (not from a mac users point of view and not from any other os users point of view) It's not mac like and not Oracle like.