# Connecting to Oracle Database from R?

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

I have searched and it seems that RODBC or Roracle are used to connect to a oracle database within R.

However, both of these packages will not install for me in R 3.1.1....am I missing something?  Is there a new/latest package that just came out that I should be using instead?

package ‘RODBC’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RODBC’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

I am using Mac OSX 10.9.4.  I tried using install.packages('RODBC').

Comment: Please state your operating system, version of R and the exact method (code) you used to do the installation.

Comment: I am using Mac OSX 10.9.4. I tried using install.packages('RODBC')

Comment: Apple has made using ODBC a bit more of a pain in the a** in Mavericks. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23419243/324364) for some details. ROracle is, if anything, more difficult to get working on a Mac, but it can be done. You'll need to compile from source again, mostly following the Linux instructions, but with some [modifications](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5550977/324364). And, of course, since both of these require compiling the packages from source, you'll need Apple's developer tools installed.

Comment: I apologize...I am not following very well.  I can't seem to install these packages on my computer / with R before I run into whatever problem awaits me afterwards.  Since I have 3.1.1 R does that just mean I am unable to connect?

Comment: No, it is possible to connect to Oracle from R on OS X. I do it daily (and have been for 2 years now). But it will require that you know what "compiling an R package from source" means. It will require that you know how to download and install Apple's developer tools (so that you actually have a compiler available with which to, you know, compile the R packages). It will require that you follow the links above and do some research about iODBC, header files, and where to put them. Start Googling, and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that message when i use 3.1.1 so I toggled to 3.1.0 using R studio.

When I am using R 3.1.0 i get the message

```
Warning message:
package ‘RODBC’ was built under R version 3.1.2
```

The package does get installed and i am able to use the functions in the package just fine.

Comment: great, it works now. I haven't tried it in several months, but it looks like the change to 3.1.2 in October has made it work now.