# Connecting to Oracle DB (on remote server) using RODBC - R

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc, roracle

I'm pretty new to R and may be I'm re-asking this question again, but I'm posting this as I didn't find an appropriate answer.

I'm trying to connect to Oracle DB that sits on a remote location from R using RODBC. I went through a lot of RODBC configuration documents but nothing clearly specifies connection to remote Oracle DB and what is the root cause.

I also pondered on using *ROracle* as DBI but found out that *RODBC* fares much better for multiple reasons.

So, here's my code:

```
> # Load RODBC package
> library(RODBC)

> # Create a connection to the database
> dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver}; Server=my_hostname; Database=my_db_name; Uid=my_uid; Pwd=my_pwd")

> # Check that connection is working
> odbcGetInfo(dbconnection)

> close(dbconnection)
```

And the TNS Config that I use *[values altered for obvious reasons]*:

```
my_db_name =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_hostname)(PORT = my_port))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = my_service_name)
  )
 )
```

*Note:* The other thing here is that I don't have a local Oracle DB setup. I use SQL Developer to connect to the remote Oracle DB with the given TNS Config.

I get the below error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver}; Server=my_hostname; Database=my_db_name; Uid=my_uid; Pwd=my_pwd") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Oracle ODBC Driver' : file not found
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver}; Server=my_hostname; Database=my_db_name; Uid=my_uid; Pwd=my_pwd") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

After installing R, I have only installed RODBC using the `install.packages("RODBC")` command. Also, I'm running this on Mac OS.

I know I'm missing something here. Specifically the `Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver}` might need to modified to the actual drivers name. But I don't know what it should be and googling didn't help much.

Is there anything else that I need to install or configure?

Comment: What are the reasons for not using ROracle?

Comment: @JoshGilfillan: I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210317/installation-of-rodbc-roracle-packages-on-os-x-mavericks) SO answer for finding some ease in getting ROracle setup, but to vain. I faced many issues while setting up ROracle on my Mac OS.