# Install ROracle in Mac

Tags: r, macos, roracle

I'm on Mac OS Sierra.

I have tried doing - [Installation of RODBC/ROracle packages on OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210317/installation-of-rodbc-roracle-packages-on-os-x-mavericks) but it didn't help.

This is what I did:

- Downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html - Basic, Sql plus, odbc
- Unzipped in my home folder in instantclient_12_1
- ln -s libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
- export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
- R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1' ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz

It gives me the following error:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -I/opt/local/include -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
rodbi.c:2432:53: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has
      type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
        sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                                                    ^~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2469:53: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has
      type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
        sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                                                    ^~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2816:55: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has
      type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
          sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                                                      ^~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2861:55: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has
      type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
          sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                                                      ^~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -I/opt/local/include -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ROracle.so rodbi.o rooci.o -L/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1 -lclntsh -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ROracle/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ROracle’
```

Someone please help.

Comment: did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

The following has worked for me on a few machines running El Capitan, so perhaps it will work on High Sierra. Unlike some other instructions, this does *not* require you to disable SIP.

1. Install the Oracle Instant Client Basic, SDK, and SQL*Plus packages. I'm pretty sure I'm not using the ODBC package, though it shouldn't get in the way if you do have it.
2. Create or edit `~/.R/Makevars`. Add the following:

   ```
   CC=/usr/bin/clang -rpath /Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1
   LDFLAGS=-L/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1
   ```

   Both the -rpath setting in `CC` and the -L linked directory in `LDFLAGS` should be the location of the Instant Client's .dylib files. If you've moved them to another location (I personally prefer to make a /lib subdirectory and put them there), that's where you should point.
3. Run the install command:

   `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/Users/dhananjaygoel/instantclient_12_1' ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz`

   with `--with-oci-lib=` pointing to the root of the Instant Client (unlike the references in Makevars, this does not, as far as I know, rely on the location of the .dylib files).

Comment: Still works for R3.6.2 and MacOS Catalina. Your mac will ask to allow the use of every .dylib file, so it takes a while but in the end you get to use ROracle

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](http://charlotte-ngs.github.io/2016/01/MacOsXrJavaProblem.html) googling around.
Just Ctrl+f (or your alternative on Mac, I'm using linux) the word "image not found" and it'll take you to the problem.
The page will lead you eventually to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite).
It's very similar to your error, however, I don't have any experience in using Mac, hope it helps though :)