# RJDBC: Connect oracle from R

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc, rjdbc

I'm trying to connect to oracle DB from R in Mac (El Capitan) using RJDBC connector . I downloaded the driver, `ojdbc6.jar` from [Oracle Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html).

In my R, I setup

> $ Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home')
>   $ options(java.parameters="-Xmx2g")
>   $ library(rJava)
>   $ library(RJDBC)
>   $ oDriver = JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
>   classPath="ojdbc6.jar")

I get error

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)) : class not found

I've also setup in my .bash_profile

> $ export ORACLE_HOME=/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2 export
>   $ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib export
>   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
>   $ export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin export
>   $ PATH="/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2:$PATH"

I'm not sure what else I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Hash

Comment: Off from the OP, but have you considered the ROracle library? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html

Comment: I tried that too, but I'm getting someother error in it. I followed the steps mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550977/installing-roracle-on-mac-os-x-what-is-needed-from-oracle). Even then I get `Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load shared object '/Library/R/3.2/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':`

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for some suggestions. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: aha! I solved the problem by reconfiguring java using `R CMD javareconf` and reinstalling `rJava`. This solved the problem.